# Password from Credential Picker

Tags: authentication, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am using Credential Picker in my Application for user authentication. authentication details in my DB are in string format. But the password that Credential Picker is passing is in encrypted form(by default Negotiate authentication protocol), So How to decry-pt that password so that i can match with my DB password.
What is the best and proper solution to do password matching with the DB stored password?
below is code snippet:

```
function launchCredentialPicker() {
    Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPicker.pickAsync("My Target", "My Message", "my Caption").then(function (results) {

        var domainName = results.credentialDomainName;
        WinJS.Application.sessionState.Username = results.credentialUserName;
        WinJS.Application.sessionState.Password = results.credentialPassword;
        WinJS.Application.sessionState.RememberPassword = (results.credentialSaveOption === Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialSaveOption.hidden) ? "Hidden" :
                               ((results.credentialSaveOption === Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialSaveOption.selected) ? "Selected" : "Unselected");

    });
}
```

Comment: Storing passwords in your database un-encrypted is a *very* bad idea..

Comment: That is different thing. Please tell how to match the password coming out from credential picker(which is encrypted and dynamically generated) with the DB password?

Comment: Is the password hashed or encrypted?  If it's hashed (most likely), you cannot determine the original password.  If it's encrypted, you'll need the shared or private key to decrypt it.

Comment: It is hashed actually with negotiate authentication protocol. So if i cannot determine the original password then how will i do my authentication process i.e. to check if the given username and password matches with my DB data. Please help as I am stucked with my app development. Thanks.

Comment: You store the hashed password in your database.  Then, when the user enters their password, you hash *that* input (using the same algorithm), then search the database for a matching hashed password.  This is basically the standard approach for this.

Comment: But while debugging, I am finding that for the same passwords i am entering, it is generating different hashes.

Comment: Perhaps each hash is salted?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `CredentialPickerOptions` object for `PickAsync` method of `CredentialPicker`. After you configure `CredentialPickerOptions` to use Basic authentication and then you will be able to see the password user entered.

```
var options = new Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPickerOptions();
options.authenticationProtocol = Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.AuthenticationProtocol.basic;

Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPicker.pickAsync(options).then(/* */);
```

Comment: Thanks but how to use other authentication protocols like Negotiation, Kerber, NTLM etc. ? As I checked in debugging mode that for the same passwords, different hashed values is returned when using these authentication protocols. So what is the use of these protocols when we have to use Basic? and if you know then please tell me how to use these protocols for Login purpose? Thanks.